# Limit ($x \to \infty$) of integral of positive and continuous function (in $\mathbb{R}$ and centered at $0$) always finite?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, piecewise-continuity

For all functions $f(x)$ that are positive and continuous everywhere in the real numbers. If $\lim\nolimits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$, is $\lim\nolimits_{x\to \infty}F(x)$ convergent for all possible $f(x)$? $F(x)$ denotes the indefinite integral of $f(x)$ centered at $0$.

I first thought so until I found a possible counterexample:
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-2}+2 & \text{if }\; x<1,\\ \frac{1}{x} & \text{if }\; x\geq 1.\end{cases}
$$

Edit: I would also like to know / possibly see a proof if my counterexample is actually valid or not.

Comment: What is your question? The statement is wrong, as you already figured out with a counterexample.

Comment: Your purported counterexample isn't continuous.

Comment: Why is it not? Both functions are defined entirely in their respective domains.

Comment: Really?  What happens at $x=1$?

Comment: Oh my bad one sec

Comment: What is the limit as $x\to 1$ from the left? I would draw the graph and see what happens there.

Comment: The question was edited. Now it is correct again. Sorry

Comment: Side note, "indefinite integral of $f(x)$ centered at zero" is slightly nonstandard terminology. If you mean the antiderivative $F$ of $f$ that satisfies $F(0) = 0$, that's given for all $t$ by $F(t) = \int_0^t f(x) \, dx$, which for any $t$ is very much a definite integral.  I tend to use "indefinite integral"/"antiderivative" only when there is no such choice of value being made. But this is a minor point.

Comment: An easier counter example to write in the same spirit is $\min(1/x,1/(x+1))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where everything is even fully differentiable on the real line.  Define $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -x+2, & x \leq 1\\
\frac{1}{x}, & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This function is continuous everywhere (in fact, differentiable) and has $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0$.    However, the antiderivative
$$F(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac{x^2}{2}+2x-\frac{3}{2}, & x \leq 1\\
\ln x, & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
will have $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = +\infty$.

**Edit:** with your updated question, yes, your counterexample is right.